# checking whether the application is launched or not and retry launching an application in blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I tried launching an application in blueprism. The application launches but again I have to give a condition that it has to check whether the application launched or not and if the application is not launched, it has to retry to launch the application.

Comment: Try to attach? If it fails, you can reasonably assume the program hasn't started. Alternatively, use the `Utility - Environment` VBO and check to see if the process is in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Once launched you can use Read stage , in the elements select in read stage drag and drop the root element in the application modellers,you will find a option as "isConnected",which will return you true or false, if result is false you can reach try.

Also for you information make sure you write logic to retry couple of times to avoid infinte loop in case problem in lunching your application